# How can I import georeferenced photos (jpg, kml, kmz) using QGIS or ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, kml, kmz, jpg

I've got several georeferenced digital photos as jpg, kml, and kmz.
How can I import them into my GIS projects (QGIS or ArcGIS for Desktop) so I can open them as a popup?

Comment: can you detail more on the nature of the photos? You have for the same jpg file a .kml/kmz?

Comment: Based on the last few words of the question I'm guessing you mean the images are actually geotagged (they have a single location representing where the camera was when the photo was taken), not georeferenced (usually aerial or satellite photos taken from more or less directly overhead).

Comment: I have edited my answer with a new link to what you want to do

Answer (score 10):

QGIS has a plugin called "[Photo2Shape](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/announcing-Photo2Shape-td4139480.html)" that will convert the geotagged coordinates of the photo into a shapefile.

You can then use the "[eVis](http://biodiversityinformatics.amnh.org/open_source/evis/)" plugin to set up hotlinks to the photos themselves, and launch a photo viewer by clicking on the attribute field.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about GeoTagged photos, I'll recommend ArcPhoto, available at http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=8C3643DC-1422-2418-8836-CF0510413D40

Answer (score 2):

See http://hub.qgis.org/projects/geotagphotos/wiki

> This plugin can be considered an upgrade of the already existing and
>   very good photo2shape plugin
>   (http://hub.qgis.org/projects/photo2shape), developed by Alexander
>   Bruy. The Geotag and import photos plugin was developed by Alexander
>   Bruy and funded/designed by Giovanni Manghi and Lolita Bizzarri to
>   respond to a specific task: manage, display and analyze photos
>   obtained from photo-trapping surveys of wildlife.

Answer (score 1):

If it's already georeferenced, for ArcGIS you could just import it as you would any other raster layer. If you need to georeference it, follow this in the helpfile:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t000000mq000000

edit:

If it is photographs rather than aerial photos, then follow this helpfile about adding HTML links/attachments to a feature class:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002r000000.htm

Now that I better understand your question, I think this is exactly what you wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ImportPhotos Plug-in:
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ImportPhotos/